# Client side is rendering faster than my data loading on server side nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to do a traffic analysis app but my client side is rendering faster than my data loading on the server side. (More specifically, it's the visual recognition data that is not being rendered on the web, I am using IBM visual recognition cloud service)

May I know how can I solve this issue? I have been stuck at this for a few days.

This is my code where I calling my function.

```
fetchAPI(10).then((data) => {
var data = data["items"][0]["cameras"]
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    image = data[i]["image"]
    images.push(image);
    coordinates.push([data[i]["location"]["latitude"], data[i]["location"]["longitude"]]);
}}).then(recognition(10, pageRender))
```

This is where I do my visual recognition

```
async function recognition(res, callback){
// Fetch api to get the images to be analyse
var data = await fetchAPI(10)
var info = await data["items"][0]["cameras"]

// Loop through the images
for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
    var image = await info[i]["image"]

    // Params to be analyse
    var params = await {
        url: image,
        classifier_ids: classifier_ids
    };

    // The part where it analyse the image
    await visualRecognition.classify(params, function(err, response) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        try{
            var status = (JSON.stringify(response.images[0]["classifiers"][0]["classes"][0]["class"], null, 2));
            var prob = (JSON.stringify(response.images[0]["classifiers"][0]["classes"][0]["score"], null, 2));
        }
        catch(error){
            status = "Error getting status"
            prob = "Error getting probability"
        }
            value.push([status, prob]);
    });
}
await callback()}
```

This is the callback function which I use to render my page.

```
function pageRender(){
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.render("index", {
        images: JSON.stringify(images),
        coordinates: JSON.stringify(coordinates),
        value: JSON.stringify(value),
    })
    console.log("I have finish rendering")
}) }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the actual problem you are having.  if a page renders fast, and the data loads slower... that seems pretty normal to me.  You are already using ajax to get the data asynchronously

Comment: The callback should have been invoked only when you get response. You need to handle the possible error responses though.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to render the on the webpage itself when it loads. Right now I am rendering the webpage without the data showing up.

Comment: Hi programmer man. May I know what do you mean by this. I am quite new to node js.